# How to find any row match by my idea with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How to find any row with idea ??.find( ip_from <=   ?my_ip?  <= to_ip ).
Please!

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO3W6.png)

Comment: Hello! Please, clarify what do you mean by "idea". Do you mean IntelliJ IDEA or another tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) for that

```
.find({ ip_from: {$lte: my_ip}, to_ip: {$gte: my_ip}});
```

Comment: Darth. Thanks you so much!